# Scrapy webscraping output missing elements from page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the SSD prices off of a url on amazon but the scraper only returns some of the prices. Please explain where I went wrong, I am new with scrapy.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider

class SSDSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "SSD_spider"
   start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search- 
   alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ssd']

   def parse(self, response):
       for ssd in response.css('.
            NAME_SELECTOR = '//span[contains(@class,"a-size-base a- 
            color-price s-price a-text-bold")]/text()'
            yield {
                'price': response.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract()
            }
```

Comment: Hey Phil, thanks for taking the time to post a question on Stack Overflow! Please also consider taking the time to check whether the indenting is actually off or not, and edit the question to add or remove spaces if needed. Indentation in Python is important, and we need to have an accurate copy of your code if we can help you.

Comment: not all of the prices have all those classes. what you want is either `a-color-price` or `s-price`

Comment: oh ok thank you!, so I assume some were not shown because they did not have both.